# Draw VISIO like diagram using GraphVIZ

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible or if any one has tried to get VISIO like diagrams using GraphViz?
I am looking for sample dot file that will draw VISIO like network diagram. As of now I am generating diagram, but those are not visually appealing. Need help on this. I am developing this tool in java where user can upload logs and the tool draws network diagram from the logs.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is funadementally a hard problem and I dare not venture in that direction . Rather than what you are trying to do have a look at some exisiting frameworks that you can leverage

1 . JGraphX : This is a graph visualization library . It ships with an excellent ready made editor called GraphEditor . You can download the examples from [here](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx).

2 . Dia : This is used to make your own network diagram elements . ( It also has a close ready to use icons for the various network elements defined in Visio . Again i suggest you to download the examples folder and peep. Check it [here](http://dia-installer.de/)

So here is what I would do :

Instead of converting dot into visio like diagrams I would try converting the dot output into the XML ( technically not 100% xml but very very close to it . ) format that the JGraphX Graph Editor understands. This can be done by mapping the x-y co-ordinates and changing the dot vertex label to the image of the network component obtained from the DIA .

It would be much much simpler .

I strongly suggest you check both the above mentioned platforms and I am sure you should have a rather simpler effort in creating the parser .

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways

1. [graphopt](https://www.schmuhl.org/graphopt/)

> Graphs can be imported using a subset of the dot format from Graphviz.
>   There is also a module to export graphs in a Visio-importable format.

2. Looks like GraphViz itself [can be built with Visio export support](http://graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/Visio-exporting-td297.html) (experimental?)

Answer (score 1):

GraphVizio is a free Visio plug-in that can import easily Graphviz diagrams into Visio. You can download it here:

https://www.calvert.ch/graphvizio/